# How to respond to ajax calls on the server side?

Tags: ajax, web-services, webserver, server

I have been working on a mobile app that sends an ajax call to the server and waits for a response from the server in json format. 
I am wondering from the server side, how to respond to an ajax call? Could someone give me an example in code? 
I check the server code of my project (written by other members of the team) and could not understand it. I can only see it is written in java and also some keywords such as apache, springframework, etc pop up. I am a total newbie for server side programming and I want to learn more about it. Could someone give me some tips on how to get started with those as well? How does a server work? Is it just like responding to various request? What language could you use to build it and what is Apache? I know this looks like a lot of questions so probably I need to get some basic knowledge first. Any help/tips/suggestions on readings is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of a broad question, as there are a lot of different server-side technologies that can handle server side AJAX requests, but if you want to go the Java route, using Spring Framework makes it very easy.

Spring Framework is a large open-source Enterprise Java framework that has a variety of features which entire books rarely even cover.

(Apache is an open-source project that contains over a hundred different sub-projects, the most popular being a web server.)

Spring does have some specific tools to handle REST calls.  Assuming your AJAX is making a REST call (which is what it sounds like), and your project is already using Spring framework, it is fairly straightforward (assuming you already know Java).  The Spring framework handles all the hard stuff for you. There are a few different ways to do this using Spring, but check out this link for creating a simple REST service:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Another route would be to look into PHP, which is a server-side scripting language.  With PHP, you can handle AJAX requests without the need for an application server (most basic web servers speak PHP).  There are plenty of good resources for this, but one of my favorites is http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/

BTW - the TutorialsPoint site is great for Java and Spring as well

Comment: I talked to them and it is Spring indeed. I gotta learn more about that. Thanks for clarifying.